# co-presence of elements from two sets in a text file

Tags: python, set, comparison, element

Disclaimer: I am new to programming and scripting in general so please excuse the lack of technical terms

I have two sets:

```
Set1 = {apple, orange, grape, banana, fruit}
Set2 = {doctor, medicine, health, sick}
```

I also have a text file composed of 1000 news articles

I want to use python syntax to determine the percentage of articles in which at least one element from `Set1`, and at least one element from `Set2`, are both present in these articles. Apologies for the lack of code - thank you for any help/insight you can provide

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't forget to tag your questions with a language (I have done this for you). Also, please post what you have attempted so far. Stop by the [help] and read [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Johnny, Thank you! Hopefully, this will help to generate some traction on the question so I can move forward... thanks again-Sincerely, Dan

Comment: If you can share what you have done so far it will help others to use it as a starting point to find a solution. Please try to share your current attempt even if it's wrong.